# Laravel Migrations create_personal_access_tokens_table 548ms FAIL

Tags: laravel, migration, syntax-error

I was Trying to use Migrations to create some tables in my database. the error i was getting is as follows:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long;
max key length is 1000 bytes (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `personal_access_tokens` add index `100`(`tokenable_type`, `tokenable_id`))

i had tried manually specifying the key length it did not do me good.

Comment: Your problem is the length of the index name. In migrations, you can specify a name for the index you are trying to create.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
I was able to deal with this issue by modifying the sting length in the AppServiceProvider.first:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;Then:
public function boot(): void{Schema::defaultStringLength(191);}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).